# Problem about fusing uwb and odom data with robot_localization

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to fuse several sensors data to locate the robot. When I'm using the great robot_localization package to fuse the uwb and odom data, a problem happens. I need to specify the two topics: the /loc generated from uwb is geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped, while the odom is nav_msgs/Odometry. That is the odometry/filtered output always very similar to (almost equals to)  the odom data or uwb data,  while my ekf_params.yaml settings are below:

```
frequency: 10
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: true
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
debug: false
debug_out_file: /home/robot/file1.txt
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false      
odom_frame: odom          
base_link_frame: base_footprint 
world_frame: odom           
odom0: /odom
odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
odom0_queue_size: 2
odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: false
odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5
odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1

pose0: /loc
pose0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
pose0_differential: false
pose0_relative: false
pose0_queue_size: 5
pose0_rejection_threshold: 2 
pose0_nodelay: false

use_control: true
stamped_control: false
control_timeout: 0.2
control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]
acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]


initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-1, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1e-1, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

And the x and y  measurements covariance of uwb and odom are set to 1e-3.
I have config the setting for days, nothing improvement, and I'm sad now.

update on  15,Jan:
Reply to Mike:  Thank you for your reply , I am using uwb sensor to get the /loc topic that only includes x and y, and wheel odometer on the two wheel differential robot to get the /odom.

Reply to Tom: Thank you for your reply , the samples are below:

**/loc:**

```
header: 
  seq: 404
  stamp: 
    secs: 1642126436
    nsecs: 242936955
  frame_id: "odom"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.0739352678571
      y: 0.090203125
      z: 0.996699772049
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0]
```

**/odom**

```
header: 
  seq: 11668
  stamp: 
    secs: 1642126444
    nsecs: 665385042
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_footprint"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0644096210599
      y: -0.163293212652
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.667035996914
      w: 0.745025455952
  covariance: [0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.000500679016113
  covariance: [0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393902/problem-about-fusing-uwb-and-odom-data-with-robot_localization/) by [HIT_LR](https://answers.ros.org/users/80867/hit_lr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-08**:
Please take a look previous answer: https://answers.ros.org/question/291794/advice-on-improving-pose-estimation-with-robot_localization/

There are many great suggestions and it will be nice to know which ones you have already tried

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-01-08**:
What sensor is providing the information that ends up on `/odom`? And on `/loc`?

Also, it would help if you explain what uwb is.

Please edit your description to add this. You edit using the "edit" button at the end of the description.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2022-01-14**:
Please include a sample sensor message for each sensor input.

**Comment by [HIT_LR](https://answers.ros.org/users/80867/hit_lr/) on 2022-01-15**:
Sorry for my late reply, it seems that I have not edit correctly since I'm new here.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-01-15**:
If uwb is a sensor, please provide a link to technical information about it. How often does it provide location data?

**Comment by [HIT_LR](https://answers.ros.org/users/80867/hit_lr/) on 2022-01-16**:
The uwb data frequency is  1Hz that set by me arbitrarily. Can be set to 5Hz, 10Hz , 20Hz......
Its error is about 0.05m to ground truth,
Any other technical information should I provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a bunch of issues here.

- You are trying to fuse two different sources of absolute pose data, but they don't agree (as in, they aren't in the same frame).

Here's your `/odom` config:

```
odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
```

And here's your `/loc` config:

```
pose0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
```

Now let's imagine that you receive a measurement on the `/odom` topic. The robot's `(X, Y)` position will jump some distance between the previous state and that measurement (how far it jumps depends on their relative covariance). Now you receive a measurement on `/loc`. That measurements says your `(X, Y)` position is somewhere totally different, so the filter will jump towards that. You are giving the filter two measurement sources and telling the filter that they are both in the same `frame_id` (*odom*) but they aren't.

If `/odom` is just wheel encoder odometry, then you should fuse the `(X, Y)` *velocity* from it, and not the absolute position:

```
odom0_config: [false,  false,  false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
```

- In addition to fusing absolutely wheel encoder positions, you are also telling the filter that each measurement has an `X` and `Y` variance of `0.001`, which is far smaller than the UWB error of `0.01`. Wheel encoder odometry error should grow over time (for pose data, not twist/velocity data). But again, you should just fuse the wheel encoder velocities. Even then, though, you should make sure your wheel encoder covariance is accurate.
- You have `two_d_mode` on, which is fine, but you aren't measuring orientation (yaw) at all. The filter expects to have a velocity or position reference for `X`, `Y`, and `Yaw` when `two_d_mode` is enabled. Without it, your yaw variance will explode, and the correlation to the other variables will cause your state to behave erratically. So you need to measure the robot's orientation. Ordinarily, I'd just say to fuse the yaw velocity from the wheel encoders:

  ```
   odom0_config: [false,  false,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true, true, false,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
  ```

However, in this case, it will create a new problem. Your integrated wheel encoder odometry yaw velocity (and absolute yaw) won't agree with your UWB sensor. In other words, if your UWB sensor says you start at `(1, 1)`, and then the next measurement is `(2, 2)`, then unless your robot is holonomic, the robot's heading should be pi/4 radians. But your wheel encoder odometry might think the robot is facing a totally different direction. So if I were you, I might modify the UWB sensor to estimate heading based on relative UWB measurements, and then fuse `X`, `Y`, and `Yaw` from that sensor.

- You have too many of the "advanced" parameters specified. You have rejection thresholds specified for your sensors, and you also have the control term enabled. You should get your state estimate behaving more or less correctly first, and then you can add those parameters to help, e.g., iron out any outlier measurements.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2022-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3